# How can I download an embeded PDF with PlayWright (python)?

Tags: python, html, pdf, playwright

I'm trying to download an embeded pdf file or get its raw content to store it in a variable using PlayWright with Python. I'm getting the following output for page.content():

''

[image]

I can't locate download button nor print button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you visit the page, playwright/chrome will need to send a network request to retrieve the PDF you're looking at. Just intercept that request, and grab the response body as a buffer.

If you are just navigating directly to the PDF, I think something like this would work:

```py
response = page.goto(url)
print(response.status)
body = response.body()

# Open file in binary write mode
pdf_file = open('file.pdf', 'wb')

# Write bytes to file
pdf_file.write(body)

# Close file
pdf_file.close()
```

Comment: I was using Chromium.. I changed it to firefox and the output for response.body() is "b'%PDF-1.4\"(...)
Thanks a lot!